# Open another class in java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I recently started learning some java, and I am facing a problem at this moment.
When an if statement is completed, I want a JFrame from another class to pop up.

So I would like something like this:

```
if(...)
{
    //open the JFrame from the other class  
}
```

My JFrame class looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {

    public static Display f = new Display();
    public static int w = 600;
    public static int h = 400;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        f.setSize(w, h);
        f.setResizable(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setTitle("Frame Test");
    }
}

class Display extends JFrame
{

}
```

Comment: you can make another display object and show it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
if(...)
{
    //open the JFrame from the other class  
    OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass();
    otherClass.setVisible(true);
}
```

You should also initialise your JFrames in the constructor, otherwise your main method will get messy

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly :). Haven't thought this was so easy.